# How can we install Docker-CE on Ubuntu 16.04 in Windows and get it to work properly?

Tags: linux, windows-10, unix, ubuntu-16.04, docker-for-windows

Not sure if anyone had ran into this issue and solved it. I had tried to research this and didn't find an answer.

So I get this warning after installing and trying to run `docker run hello-world`.

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?. See 'docker run --help'.
```

I have been trying to properly install docker-ce on Ubuntu 16.04 in Windows since I only have Windows 10 Home version. Do not plan to upgrade my Windows 10 to any other versions. I had tried a couple of things. I had looked at several sources and followed the instructions but still had that issue.

https://medium.com/@sebagomez/installing-the-docker-client-on-ubuntus-windows-subsystem-for-linux-612b392a44c4

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1

I ran `sudo systemctl status docker` and got this error:

```
The command could not be located because '/usr/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
service: command not found
```

I solved this issue by setting PATH

```
PATH="/sbin:$PATH"
```

Taken from this article:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/972611/why-does-sbin-not-included-in-path-for-new-user

After this, I ended up running `sudo service docker status` and it shows Docker is not running so I ran `sudo service docker start`

I checked the status and again and it says running now. I ran `docker info` and got the following:

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.6
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.89GiB
Name: DESKTOP-MA8QOES
ID: AD4R:WH7W:VHRE:ZSMY:GIE7:7ZTC:G4FK:L6AV:OTMY:QLC3:B7H3:LRC2
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpu shares support
WARNING: No cpuset support
```

I test `sudo docker run hello-world` again got this message:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
1b930d010525: Extracting [==================================================>]     977B/977B
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): invalid argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Not sure what to do at this point now... Any help would be greatly appreciated.